# How can I find out the result of my calendar intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, google-calendar-api

From my app I am launching the calendar with an intent:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
    startActivity(intent);
```

I cannot figure out how to get the eventID back if the user goes ahead and saves this pre-populated calendar entry. I also want to know if the user cancelled the calendar prompt, and did not save this new pre-populated event.

<strike>Is there anything relevant returned to onActivityResult(...) which I could use as a reference to the calendar event? I need this, so I can later find/open the calendar event for viewing/editing.</strike>
[Update:] Yea, tried onActivityResult(...), and the intent returns as soon as the calendar opens before any user interaction, so this is no use.

I would like to do this by handing off to the calendar application by using an intent(also to let the user select from the various calendars available on the device) and avoid recreating the calendar UE from my app. Also I would like to support Android 2.2+ at the very least.

Comment: Hi, Have you found solution? I have the almost the same problem, I want get ID of created event. Details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508511/calendar-event-intent-startactivityforresult

Comment: No, I ended up using the webapi and skip the android calendar api: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ If I recall

Comment: If I recall correctly, my decision was lead by the requirement to support early platform versions (2.1+). I was investigating various ways,and  I did not want to rely on any existing but unsupported API functionalities in the earlier versions of the Android platform.

Comment: Thanks. I am facing the same problem and I am thinking about proper solution for a weeks. In my app I need to create repeating todo events and pushing it into default calendar looks like ideal solution. But it's not, because some devices doesn't have default calendar. Also unsupported 2.1+ calendar api is problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can check event by beginTime in onResume method. There definitely won't be 2 events with the same beginTime.

Comment: Good idea, I can figure something out from here. However, can the user change the beginTime from the Calendar screen which is effectively the date of the event? Or that can never be changed by the user?

Answer (score 10):

This is what I do:

I get the next Event Id before starting the intent:

```
public static long getNewEventId(ContentResolver cr) {      
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, new String [] {"MAX(_id) as max_id"}, null, null, "_id");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long max_val = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("max_id"));     
    return max_val+1;
}
```

Then, I call the intent like usual:

```
        long event_id = EventUtility.getNewEventId(mContext.getContentResolver());

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(Events._ID, event_id)
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "title");

        startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the trick, in onResume() of my activity I check if there is new event_id created same as the event_id generated previously. If they are same, means the new calendar has been created. Then, I store the new on my database.

```
public static long getLastEventId(ContentResolver cr) {      
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Events.CONTENT_URI, new String [] {"MAX(_id) as max_id"}, null, null, "_id");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long max_val = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("max_id"));     
    return max_val;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    long prev_id = EventUtility.getLastEventId(getContentResolver());

    // if prev_id == mEventId, means there is new events created
    // and we need to insert new events into local sqlite database.
    if (prev_id == mEventID) {
        // do database insert
    }
}
```

Comment: This certainly seems like the best approach to the problem.

Comment: this works for me, but note that getLastEventId and getNewEventId are almost exactly the same, so you cans ave yourself some duplication

Comment: note that `getNewEventId` assumes that the next event id is equal to the   last event id + 1, but that is not true if you (1) add event, (2) add event, (3) delete the event from previous step, (4) add event

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can insert the event programmatically and send an intent to 'edit' it.

Comment: Could do, but in that case if the user cancels the Calendar screen (which I opened with an intent to edit), the programmatically created event will remain in the calendar unused. I will have no idea finding out if the user saved or cancelled the Calendar intent for the event.

Comment: You can check modified date of created event onResume.. if date is exact as create=> user cancel, otherwise user saved it which means accepted implicitly ... I dont say this approach is ideal .. yodann's way is better

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a hack.. However, you could check in OnCreate (when your application comes to foreground from the calendar application) whether the fired event is saved or cancelled by querying the calendar entries using calendar provider apis.

Comment: Hi, this is where I was going with my thought process. However, should I really do something at onCreate or at onStart? What shall I check for, the eventID?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling `startActivity(intent)`, you can call `startActivityForResult(intent, integer_constant)` and override `onActivityResult` method.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Unfortunately this approach won't work with any Calendar application. With native google app it doesn't work, with Samsung's calendar app it works.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want to use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity.  There's some documentation for it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Comment: This does not work with the Calendar intent. This is my code when I try that and this returns immediately when the calendar intent starts.    <code>public void addcalendarevent(View view){
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);startActivityForResult(intent, SET_CALENDAR);                      </code>

Comment: Sorry you can see above that I clearly do not know how to format a comment on StackOverflow. My point was that the intent returns onActivityResult immediately when starting it (with startActivityForResult).