# getting event ID after creating it using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

(first of all, sorry if any of this sounds stupid, but I'm a total nood regarding android)

I'm working on an organizer app where I want to create a Calendar Event using an intend, and afterwards I have to save the events ID in my app so I can open it up again to edit it and so my app can read the events start date.

the code I'm using, I got from this question:
 [How can I find out the result of my calendar intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761584/how-can-i-find-out-the-result-of-my-calendar-intent)
The intend works but I can't get the rest to work. also, "EventUtility" and "mContext" show up as errors.

p.s. I also get a warning about a missing Permission but I have no idea where to add that

```
protected void kalender() {
    long event_id = EventUtility.getNewEventId(mContext.getContentResolver());
    Intent newEvent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Abgabe Termin")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true)
            .putExtra("allDay", true);
    startActivity(newEvent);

}


public static long getNewEventId(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"MAX(_id) as max_id"}, null, null, "_id");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long max_val = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("max_id"));
    return max_val + 1;
}
```

Comment: Which permission are you missing? You add those in the Manifest file.
Also, what kind of errors do "EventUtility" and "mContext" have?

Comment: @bensadiku the permission is "READ_CALENDAR" and for the other two I get "Cannot resolve symbol". so, do i have to specify those somewhere earlier in the code?

Comment: These are the permissions you need for the calendar.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>`

As for the "Cannot resolve symbol", you do need to specify the type of these variables earlier on, yes.

Comment: @bensadiku but as what type do I specify them?